Is there a single generator for the Boolean clone generated by conjunction and disjunction?
Consider the set $\{0,1\}$, and consider the clone (in the sense of universal algebra) generated by $\{\land, \vee\}$, which is conjunction and disjunction, respectively. Is there a single operation, whether binary or of a higher arity than binary, that generates the clone generated by conjunction and disjunction?

Consider the function $f(a,b,c,d) = (a \vee b) \wedge (c \vee d)$. Then $f(a,a,b,b) = a \wedge b$ and $f(a,b,a,b) = a \vee b$. So the clone generated by $f$ would contain both $\vee, \wedge$, and conversely $\vee, \wedge$ suffice to define $f$.

+1. More generally, any clone generated by finitely many idempotent operations can be generated by a single operation.
